# GCE: Zone A (Discarded) - ... After this Date all instances will be Discarded. What to do?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Engine instance running, and today i saw that there is an Notification that

> Zone A (Discarded) - After this Date, all instances will be Discarded.

Does that mean that my Instance will be deleted when i don´t set another Zone? 
Do i have to Set up a new Zone reconfigure my Load-Balancer and everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring the [deprecated europe-west1-a zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#october152014), yes you should move all your resources to another zone and reconfigure your load balancer as this zone will be completely turn down and therefore all the resources in that zone will be deleted after March 29th, 2015.

This link, will help you to [move instances between zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#moving_an_instance_between_zones)